# foreach loop and returning value of undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach, undefined, return-value

I was wondering if anyone could explain me why this function return ***`undefined`*** instead of founded object

```
var people = [
  {name: 'John'},
  {name: 'Dean'},
  {name: 'Jim'}
];

function test(name) {
  people.forEach(function(person){
    if (person.name === 'John') {
      return person;
    }   
  });
}

var john = test('John');
console.log(john);

// returning 'undefined'
```

Comment: how should look like the result?

Comment: returning result that i expect should look like { name: 'John'}

Comment: Returning from the inner function does not magically return from the outer function.Since `test` doesn't have a return statement, it returns `undefined`. Simplified example: `function outer() { function inner () { return 42; }}; outer();` will return `undefined`

Comment: Felix, thanks for great explanation

Comment: Also, [please use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+return+forEach+undefined).

Answer (score 7):

Returning into `forEach` loop won't work, you are on the `forEach` callback function, not on the test() function. So  instead you need to return the value from outside the `forEach` loop.

```js
var people = [{
  name: 'John'
}, {
  name: 'Dean'
}, {
  name: 'Jim'
}];

function test(name) {
  var res;
  people.forEach(function(person) {
    if (person.name === 'John') {
      res = person;
    }
  });
  return res;
}

var john = test('John');
console.log(john);
```

Or for finding a single element from array use **[find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**

```js
var people = [{
  name: 'John'
}, {
  name: 'Dean'
}, {
  name: 'Jim'
}];

function test(name) {
  return people.find(function(person) {
    return person.name === 'John';
  });
}

var john = test('John');
console.log(john);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities

A result set with [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
// return the result set
function test(name) {
    return people.filter(function(person){
        return person.name === 'John';
    });
}
```

or a boolean value if the given name is in the array with [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
// returns true or false
function test(name) {
    return people.some(function(person){
        return person.name === 'John';
    });
}
```